# Fixed-size array of objects and sub-objects on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I've searched and searched but haven't found anything that really clears up my confusion.

I'm representing a grid, and have two classes, e.g.:

```
class Term {
   ...
};

class GridPoint{
   Term a;
   Term b;
   Term c;
   ...
};
```

I would like to have a large, fixed-size array on the heap, where each element of the array is a GridPoint, itself containing multiple Terms.

However, the following example will not compile:

```
GridPoint* pGrid = new GridPoint[100][100];
```

According to gcc:

> error: cannot convert ‘GridPoint (*)[100]’ to ‘GridPoint*’ in initialization

Comment: `auto *pGrid = new GridPoint[100][100];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First I would like to suggest *not* using `new` and `delete` in modern C++, instead use *smart pointers* or containers from the standard library that encapsulates this as e.g. `std::vector`.

That being said, to get your example to work you have to initialize an array of arrays in a loop like so:

```
GridPoint** pGrid = new GridPoint*[100];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 100; ++i) {
    pGrid[i] = new GridPoint[100];
}

// Do something...

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != 100; ++i) {
    delete[] pGrid[i];
}
delete[] pGrid;
```

For a better alternative simply use `std::array` or `std::vector`:

```
std::array<std::array<GridPoint, 100>, 100> pGrid;
```

**Note:** `std::array` encapsulates a static array that it uses to store its data. This means that if you allocate a `std::array` object with automatic storage duration its data will *not* be dynamically allocated (the data will not be on the "heap").

`std::vector` will however store its data using dynamic allocation.

Comment: The `std::array` is not "on the heap"

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah you're right, I included an example of `std::array` usage as it shows the simplicity of it in contrast to using the raw memory allocation syntax.

Comment: -1 for presenting `new[]` and `delete[]` first.

Comment: @Puppy Ok, added some "correctness" to the answer.